# Need help button select all text from p id and copy it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i have div class drop down, when I select a specific option from drop down it will pull out the P ID and will show text and images. What I am trying to do is to have a button that will select all text/images inside the  to copy it to clipboard.

Here is my sample div dropdown code:

```
<div class="button dropdown"> 
<select id="colorselector">
<option>Select Email templates here</option>
<option value="1st">R17 Update</option>
<option value="2nd">Reset Password</option>
</select>
</div>
```

When a user choose from the drop down it will show p id body text and image

```
<!---------------------------- P ID 1st---------------------->
<div id="1st" class="colors yellow"> 
<br> 
<p>Sample text</p>
<br>
<p>Sample text/p> 
<br>
<p>Sample text</p>
<br>
<p>Sample Image</a></p>
<img src="https://i.screenshot.net/dl/8j82ein?name=4.jpg" alt="">
<br>
<br> 
</div>

<!---------------------------- P ID 2nd---------------------->
<div id="2nd" class="colors red">
<br> 
<p>Sample text</p>
<br>
<p>Sample text/p> 
<br>
<p>Sample text</p>
<p>Sample Image</p>
<img src="https://i.screenshot.net/dl/8j82ein?name=4.jpg" alt="">
<br>
<font color="#08298A">Kind Regards,
<br> 
</div>
```

Now what I need is a button that will highlight the text/image on the p id to copy it to clipboard

Example:

A user select R17 option from the drop down

It will show the content of it which is:

> Sample text
>
> Sample text
>
> Sample text
>
> Sample Image (Image here)

Then when a user cick the button below it will highlight all text/image or will select all content of the P I.D to copy it.

Thanks in advance for the help everyone!

Comment: I assume by "select" you mean display?

Comment: That is correct @theblackips

Answer (score 0):

This code hides your templates by default and displays them when the button is clicked. You will need to add the class `template` to all your templates for this to work.

```js
function displayTemplate() {
  // hide all templates
  var templates = document.getElementsByClassName('template');
  for(var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++)
  {
    templates.item(i).classList.remove('show');
  }
  
  // show selected template
  selector = document.getElementById('colorselector');
  templateId = selector.value;
  if (templateId !== '') {
    template = document.getElementById(templateId);
    template.classList.add('show');
  }
}
```

```css
.template {
  display: none;
}

.template.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="button dropdown"> 
<select id="colorselector">
<option value="">Select Email templates here</option>
<option value="1st">R17 Update</option>
<option value="2nd">Reset Password</option>
</select>
</div>

<button onclick="displayTemplate()">Display template</button>

<!---------------------------- P ID 1st---------------------->
<div id="1st" class="colors yellow template"> 
<br> 
<p>Sample text</p>
<br>
<p>Sample text/p> 
<br>
<p>Sample text</p>
<br>
<p>Sample Image</a></p>
<img src="https://i.screenshot.net/dl/8j82ein?name=4.jpg" alt="">
<br>
<br> 
</div>

<!---------------------------- P ID 2nd---------------------->
<div id="2nd" class="colors red template">
<br> 
<p>Sample text</p>
<br>
<p>Sample text</p> 
<br>
<p>Sample text</p>
<p>Sample Image</p>
<img src="https://i.screenshot.net/dl/8j82ein?name=4.jpg" alt="">
<br>
<font color="#08298A">Kind Regards,
<br> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and I would like to have a second button "Copy" and it will copy the content of the template. How do I do that?